# Should I remove listeners before deleting a custom object?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I load into an empty movieclip (via addChild) a library object (a movieclip of class MyObject that extends the MovieClip class). At some point, from the main I remove this custom movieclip from its parent and I set any reference to null to completely destroy it. The question: what if in the custom movieclip class there are eventListeners? Are them deleted when I destroy the object? Should I write a method to remove them before deleting the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you should clean up all the internal references in in object if you are trying to destroy it for garbage collection purposes.  You can also create your listeners with weak references to make them auto-destroy by passing the fifth argument as `true`, but I personally recommend not using weak references and getting into the habit of properly cleaning up manually.

```
//setting a weak referenced listener
foo.addEventListener(Event.WHATEVER,bar(),false,0,true);
```

Comment: Is there a way from inside the custom object to get a reference to any of the listeners created? The goal would be that of eventually delete them from inside a loop. Is it possible?

Comment: Not really, because you are presumably registering the listeners onto different objects, and `addEventListener` doesn't return anything so you can't store a reference.  I find the best way if you are going to register all your listeners at once is to have functions called `addListeners` and `removeListeners`, which makes maintenance a bit easier, but is not much use if you add listeners at different intervals in your execution.

Comment: Very strangely, when I try to remove all the listeners at once I get an error #1009.

Comment: Forget what I said, it was a totally unrelated issue. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove all event listeners (or if you are lazy, use weak referencing when you add the event listeners) or there will still be internal references to the object preventing the garbage collector from collecting it.

Comment: If I asked this is because I'm not lazy (not completely)   ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I include some type of `destroy()` method in just about every class I write. This method is responsible for all instances of or references to any child objects in that class. This includes any listeners, display list references etc. Then, before I go to remove/null the parent, I call its `destroy()` method to assure proper GC and avoid memory leaks. Note that this can chain down deeply nested objects, if need be.

You *could* just use weak references and remove the whole object. ASVM2 is generally smart enough to properly kill child objects *BUT* this is poor GC management, at best, and you are just asking for memory leaks.

My $.02.